# How to make my program run at startup using installsheild

Tags: vb.net, startup, installshield-le

I was wondering how can I my program to run at windows start-up using the registry editor in installsheild limited edition in visual studio 2012. The program is a timer for individual users and for it work properly it needs to e able to run automatically at startup. it's written in vb.net, incase it's important.

I did see a similar question which point that i can do it using the following line:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath)
```

but i was wondering how to do it using the installsheild.

Comment: Have you added an Installshield wizard to your solution/project? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yea, I added one, but I don't know how to add the run at start-up in the registry section of the installsheild.

Comment: either of these help: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpRegistryKeys.htm or http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/636479/How-can-I-set-in-Installshield-to-run-my-applicati

Comment: sorry but I've seen these both before, but I can't understand the solution on codeproject. I'm not sure if it's saying that i should copy currently existing registry or just create one, but i have no idea where i should create it and what should i set the value to be

Comment: Really depends on your version of VS (do you have Pro version). I suggest youtube videos, with the same version you have

Comment: I have the 2012 ultimate version

Comment: I've looked through YouTube there are no videos that show how to make the program run at startup after installing it. All of the installshield videos are just showing how to make a simple install exe.